# spring-integration-kafka xml multiple topics not working

Tags: spring-integration

My project works just fine if there's just one topic defined in XML file. When I'm trying to add another topic, it just can't produce any message of either topic.
My XML file is like below:

```
<int-kafka:producer-configurations>
    <int-kafka:producer-configuration broker-list="127.0.0.1:9092"
                   topic="test"         
                   key-class-type="java.lang.String"
                   value-class-type="java.lang.String"
                   value-encoder="encoder"
                   key-encoder="encoder"
                   compression-type="none"
                />
    <int-kafka:producer-configuration broker-list="127.0.0.1:9092"
                   topic="test2"            
                   key-class-type="java.lang.String"
                   value-class-type="java.lang.String"
                   value-encoder="encoder"
                   key-encoder="encoder"
                   compression-type="none"
                />
</int-kafka:producer-configurations>
```

Anyone who knows about my problem would be great help, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are not providing any information as to which topic to route to.

When there is only one topic, in that situation, it will be used.

If there are more than one, you will get an exception:

```
throw new IllegalStateException("Could not send messages as there are multiple producer configurations " +
                "with no topic information found from the message header.");
```

By default, the adapter will look for the topic to route to in the `kafka_topic` message header.

You can also provide a `topic-expression`, e.g. `topic-expression="headers['foo']"` and the topic will be obtained from the `foo` header.

Comment: That's the problem, if I provide " topic='test' " I can produce message for topic 'test' now.  But still, If I want to produce both 'test' and 'test2' , that won't help. I'm considering using 'topic-expression' and I tried your example but it didn't work.. Is there any details I was missing by the way?  My Producer is like this: channel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload('test-message').setHeader("messageKey", "key").setHeader("topic", "test").build());

Comment: `topic-expression="headers['topic']` should work. You don't need `topic` or `topic-expression` if you use `setHeader("kafka_topic", "test")`. The message key header needs to be `setHeader("kafka_messageKey", "key")` unless you have an `expression-key-expression`. It looks like you are using old header names from 0.5; they were changed to have the `kafka_` prefix in 1.0, to be consistent with the rest of the framework and avoid collisions with headers from other modules.

Comment: Thanks Gary, your answer perfectly solved my problem, after rewriting the message header and topic-expression, my kafka can produce and consume multiple-topic messages right now.

Comment: Good. If an answer solves your problem, it is customary here to mark it as 'accepted' (tick/check mark underneath the vote counter on the left). It will help other users searching for similar answers.